# how to create the Inference configuration files for Deepstream (nvinferserver) for Tao Zoo models

Tags: deepstream

I’m trying to use the Tao Zoo models with Triton and Deepstream using the nvinferserver component with GRPC.

I found the models and their pbtxt configuration files for Triton in GitHub - NVIDIA-AI-IOT/tao-toolkit-triton-apps: Sample app code for deploying TAO Toolkit trained models to Triton 1

and I found the configuration files for deepstream deepstream_reference_apps/README.md at master · NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_reference_apps · GitHub, they work for the nvinfer component, but not with the nvinferserver

can you provide these configuration files? I think it can be valuable for many people using Deepstream with Triton.

Regards.